# The Constructor Intent is undefined?

Tags: android, android-intent

I trying to add settings into my first Android app, but I have problem with intent, code is:

```
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
     Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
     startActivity(intent1);    
     return true;
 }
```

And error is:

```
The constructor Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment, Class<Settings>) is undefined
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to this form of `Intent` constructor is a `Context`. Your `NavigationDrawerFragment` is not a `Context` while an `Activity` would be. You can use `getActivity()` for a `Context` in a fragment:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), Settings.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using :

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), Settings.class);
startActivity(intent1);    
return true;
```

Instead of :

```
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
 startActivity(intent1);    
 return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change **this** to **getActivity**() or **YourActivity.this**

.